# Export collection in mongodb using shell command

Tags: json, mongodb, export, export-to-csv

I want to export collection in mongodb using shell command: 
I try the following command but fields with ":" (number:phone, number:fax) are not exported.

```
mongoexport --csv -d schemaName -c collectionName -q "{typeName:'user'}" -f "name, surname, e-mail, number:phone, number:fax" -o export.csv
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the document that you're trying to export?

Comment: This is the example document.
`{'path': '/users/sarahperez', 'name':'Sarah', 'surname':'Perez', 'e-mail':'sarahperez@sarahperez.com','number:phone':'00421236523','number:fax':'004215377853'}
{'path': '/users/ericeldon', 'name':'Eric', 'surname':'Eldon', 'e-mail':'ericeldon@ericeldon.com','number:phone':'00421276823','number:fax':'0042165928725'}`
@Jenna

Comment: Hmm, I think the issue may have to do with the fact that the field name has a colon in it. I can export the fields of an embedded document such as {number: {fax: 123, cell: 345}} using the dot notation.  I'll keep investigating.

Comment: you can export it okay as JSON just not CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have found a legitimate bug. The `mongoexport` tool is rarely used and the colon means something very specific when parsing JSON, so the tool is probably confused.

You can file the bug here: http://jira.mongodb.org/